# "global" information available throughout mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, viewbag

I need to be able to access (add/edit/update) a few basic bits of information throughout the lifetime of my application.  When a user logs in they are able to go to a page in the app and select a contract, I want to be able to access the contract reference number and company name anywhere in my application. Viewbag and viewdata seem to be something to stay away from, so whats the best way to do this ?  Ive considered creating a base class that holds the contract ref and company name and then every model and view model I create will inherit from this base class and the contract ref can be updated from controller to controller for each different model.  Is this considered good practice or is there a better way

Comment: what about keeping this in a database?

Comment: Create new session data and add your contract reference number and company name this session data

Comment: Better to go with Database approach.

Comment: MVC is a stateless framework. Holding items in session contradicts this by trying to persist state. In process Session state is also not scalable when adding more than 1 web server. Your suggestion of the base view model is in my opinion the best way forward. You then pass this information around the models throughout the life of your users session. You did originally say "Life time of application"... i presume you mean "users session" as the session and application are different things.

Comment: the data is stored in a database. Ill give you an example of why I need things like a contract ref to be available throughout my app. Users can generate a whole bunch of reports,some are for a particular company, others for a specific contract reference, so for example a current user can select a contract as the 'currently selected' contract, then pick from a whole bunch of reports for the current contract

Comment: @proteus - Seems reasonable. So once they have selected the contract ref, lets say from a drop down populated from the Db.. when you click your action link or submit button, whatever mechanism it is you have... post that ref from the views form to your controller/action... and persist in the new view model of the next view.